# How can I remove or hide foreign language fonts from macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, font, font-book

My font menu is long and crowded with a lot of foreign language fonts that I never use.

Is there a way to remove or hide them them safely and easily from macOS Catalina?

Comment: Have you opened Font Book and tried to disable them ?

Comment: This comes up a lot in the ASC, you might want to search there,  example. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255068830?sortBy=oldest_first

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't disable them in Font Book, then sadly: no.

There was an app called "Font Menu Cleaner", which did offer this ability, but it has been withdrawn because of subsequent changes in the OS (in Ventura) that stopped it from working.

For any app that uses Apple's font panel (like TextEdit, Pages, etc); you can select the "English" font Collection, which should only list fonts with  European alphabets. This may also exclude any symbol fonts you have, too.

[image]

You can of course leave [Apple feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) and complain about the inability to disable the countless fonts that it adds to the OS.

Comment: It’s very reasonable to want a shorter menu. I wonder if Apple would fix that since they may know that the fonts are needed in case someone changes a setting and then the system won’t boot…

Comment: @bmike Yes, but "how many fonts does it take to boot an OS?" Do I need to boot into Egyptian Hieroglyph, Cuneiform, Linear B..... ?

Comment: If you boot in recovery, you can choose other localizations and render the experience invalid or broken - but it sure seems reasonable to not want to see them in the menu once you’ve expressed a choice of locale.

Comment: @bmike I'm not suggesting that anything should break. There's no need for ... <checks> 81 System fonts and 289 "Supplemental" fonts, most of which cannot be disabled. These are in addition to the 54 suitcases for the UI that are invisible, whose names start with dot.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Looks like I'll just go through FontBook and start turning fonts off one-by-one.